# How do I increment an int value in an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, nsmutablearray

I got:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    int index_counter;
    //NSMutableArray *logins;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *count;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *logins;
- (IBAction)next_button:(id)sender;
@end
```

Which is an array that holds objects:

```
@interface THEOBJECT : NSObject 
{
    NSString *uname;
    int counter;
}
-(void) SetUser: (NSString *) username;
-(void) SetCount: (int) value;
-(void) print;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *uname; 
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) int counter; //not sure if this is correct
@end

@implementation SiteValue

@synthesize uname;
@synthesize counter;


-(void) SetCount:(int) value
{
    counter=counter+1;    
}

@end
```

and my method should increment the count value in the object THEOBJECT in each index of the array:

```
- (IBAction)next_button:(id)sender
{
    index_counter=index_counter-1;
    if (index_counter<0)
    {
        index_counter=0;
    }
    username.text=[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] uname];
    [[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] counter]=[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] counter]+1; //ERROR HERE.
}
```

Where I wrote "ERROR HERE", it should increment the count value every time I push the *next* button and store +1 in the array. **But it's giving me a readonly error.** The exact error is `"assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed"`. I think the best thing to do is to call the `setcount:` method but it's not letting me call it since it's two different interfaces. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here. But it looks very convoluted. Try setCounter: new counter value. Not sure why you are keeping an index within the model object when you can always get the index and count from NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to access the property `counter`, but to do that you need to cast the result of `objectAtIndex:` as it returns an `id` and while Objective-C allows you to call any method on an `id` instance you cannot call any property:

```
((THEOBJECT *)[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter]).counter++;
```

Answer (score 1):

`counter` in this line is an accessor method:

```
[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] counter]
```

It returns a value to you so it's not something you can set (It's like saying `50 = 100` -- you cannot set a value like that).

If you want to set the variable, you need to use the `setCounter` method:

```
[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] setCounter:[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] counter]+1];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] counter]=[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] counter]+1; //ERROR HERE.
```

You should be using the setter and not the getter of the property `counter`on the left side of the assignment. So you should change that line into:

```
[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] setCounter:[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] counter]+1];
```

To make this clearer, you can split that line into two lines:

```
int currentValue = [[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] counter];
[[logins objectAtIndex:index_counter] setCounter:currentValue+1];
```

You can also use the dot notation and write that as:

```
THEOBJECT *myObject = [logins objectAtIndex:index_counter];
int currentValue = myObject.counter;
myObject.counter = currentValue + 1;
```

Or:

```
THEOBJECT *myObject = [logins objectAtIndex:index_counter];
myObject.counter = myObject.counter + 1;
```

Or:

```
THEOBJECT *myObject = [logins objectAtIndex:index_counter];
myObject.counter++;
```